# Removing a prefix from files recursively in ssh

Tags: linux, unix

I have a load of folders of images (a lot!) and some of the thumbnails have a 'tn' prefix, while others don't, so in order to be able to write a gallery for all, I'm trying to remove the 'tn' from the beginning of the files that have it recursively in the entire directory.

So, an offending thumbnail would have the files :

```
tngal001-001.jpg
tngal001-002.jpg
tngal001-003.jpg
```

etc...

and I need them to be :

```
gal001-001.jpg
gal001-002.jpg
gal001-003.jpg
```

or even better still... if I could get the whole `tngal001-` off, that'd be amazing, so, in the directory `gallery` I have:

```
gal001/thumbnails/tngal001-001.jpg
gal001/thumbnails/tngal001-002.jpg
gal001/thumbnails/tngal001-003.jpg 
etc...

gal002/thumbnails/tngal002-001.jpg
gal002/thumbnails/tngal002-002.jpg
gal002/thumbnails/tngal002-003.jpg 
etc...

gal003/thumbnails/tngal003-001.jpg
gal003/thumbnails/tngal003-002.jpg
gal003/thumbnails/tngal003-003.jpg 
etc...
```

and I'd prefer to have:

```
gal001/thumbnails/001.jpg
gal001/thumbnails/002.jpg
gal001/thumbnails/003.jpg 
etc...

gal002/thumbnails/001.jpg
gal002/thumbnails/002.jpg
gal002/thumbnails/003.jpg 
etc...

gal003/thumbnails/001.jpg
gal003/thumbnails/002.jpg
gal003/thumbnails/003.jpg 
etc...
```

I have tried `find . -type f -name "tn*" -exec sh -c 'for f; do mv "$f" "{f#tn}"; done' find sh {} +`

and `find . -type f -exec sh -c 'for file in tn*; do mv "$file" "${file#tn}"; done' findsh {} +`

but I'm not getting it quite right. I just want to understand how to strip off the letters/rename recursively, as I'm just getting my head around this stuff. All the other questions I have found seem to be talking about stripping out characters from file names and all the ascii characters and escaping spaces etc are confusing me. I would appreciate it if someone could explain it in plain(ish) english. I'm not stupid, but I am a newbie to linux! I know it's all logical once I understand what's happening.

Thanks in advance, Kirsty

Comment: Is there ANY possibility that `gal001-001.jpg` may already exist in the SAME directory as `tngal001-001.jpg`?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
find . -type f -name "tn*" -exec sh -c '
  for f; do
    fname=${f##*/}
    mv -i -- "$f" "${f%/*}/${fname#tn*-}"
  done
' sh {} +
```

You need to split `"$f"` into the parent path and filename before you start to remove the prefix from the filename. And you forgot to add a `$` in your parameter expansion (`${f#tn}`).

- `${f##*/}` removes the longest prefix `*/` and leaves the filename, e.g.

  ```
  gal001/thumbnails/tngal001-001.jpg -> tngal001-001.jpg
  ```

  (the same result as `basename "$f"`)
- `${f%/*}` removes the shortest suffix `/*` and leaves the parent path, e.g.

  ```
  gal001/thumbnails/tngal001-001.jpg -> gal001/thumbnails
  ```

  (the same result as `dirname "$f"`)
- `${fname#tn*-}` removes the shortest prefix `tn*-` from the filename, e.g.

  ```
  tngal001-001.jpg -> 001.jpg
  ```

I added the `-i` option to prompt to overwrite an already existing file.

Comment: Hi. Firstly, thanks for your reply! But, for this I received the error `sh: -c: line 1: sytax error: unexpected end o file`

Comment: Sorry, can't reproduce the error. Try to copy & paste the whole script into your shell.

Comment: I didn't realise you could do that in Putty, but I just googled it and found you could! Yes, that worked... however now I need the big images' names to match the thumbnails... so, I also need to strip the `gal001-`off the front of those jpgs. From your explanation, I would understand it that this should easily work, just taking off the `tn`, so having this : ```find . -type f -name "tn*" -exec sh -c '
  for f; do
    fname=${f##*/}
    mv -i -- "$f" "${f%/*}/${fname#*-}"
  done
' sh {} +``` however I've just tried it, and the files are still the same. Have I understood this correctly?

Comment: Just realised my mistake! I didn't edit the first 'tn'. It's working now.

Comment: Thanks! I think I understand this... And now all the files look like organised bliss! You have no idea how happy you've made me. I've been trying for 3 days to get them done.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop over all the folders and files in your `gallery` and then rename them as following.

Assuming you have your folder structure as

```
gallery/
gallery/gal001
gallery/gal002
gallery/gal003
...
gallery/gal001/thumbnails/
gallery/gal002/thumbnails/
gallery/gal003/thumbnails/
...
gallery/gal001/thumbnails/tngal001-001.jpg
gallery/gal001/thumbnails/tngal001-002.jpg
gallery/gal001/thumbnails/tngal001-002.jpg
```

Move to your `gallery` using `cd gallery` then run the following code

```
for j in *;
 do
    cd $j/thumbnails; 
    for i in  *; 
     do 
       echo "Renaming $j/thumbnails/$i --> $(echo $i|sed "s/tn$j-//1")";
       mv -i $i $(echo $i|sed "s/tn$j-//1"); 
     done
    cd ../..; 
done
```

**Explanation**

```
for j in *;
```

loops over all the folders in `gallery` ie `j` contains `gal001, gal002, gal003, etc.`

```
cd $j/thumbnails;
```

moves inside 'gal001/thumbnails' direcotry.

```
for i in  *; do
```

loops over all the files in the directory `gal001/thumbnails` and name of the file is contained in `i`.

```
echo "Renaming $j/thumbnails/$i --> $(echo $i|sed "s/tn$j-//1")"
```

Prints the file name and to which it is being renamed to. (Remove it if you don't want verbose).

```
mv $i $(echo $i|sed "s/tn$j-//1"); done
```

`mv -i $i newname` Renames `$i` (value of current file in loop). `-i` flag to prompt if the file name after rename already exist.

`sed` is stream editor, takes the `filename` by *piping* `$i` into sed,

`"s/previous/new/1"` replaces first occurence of `previous` value with `new` value in the stream. Here, replaces value of `tn` + `j` (which is name of directory `gal001`) i.e. `tngal001-` with "null string" (nothing between `//`).

`cd ../..` to move back to `gallery`.

Comment: Many thanks... but when I tried this, I got the following error: `-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `;'`

Comment: must have been a formatting problem. The code works fine on my side. I have reformatted my snippet. Must work fine now. :)